# Is it possible to make an electromagnet have south poles formed at both ends?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

As far as I am concerned, all magnets have 1 N and 1 S pole, but I think I
might be missing something.

Is it possible to make an electromagnet have south poles formed at both ends?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/714282/

Comment: Sort of possible. You can glue the north poles of two bar magnets together. Now you have a magnet where magnetic field lines come out the middle and go in the ends.

Comment: Worth noting - the north and south labels on a magnet are useful in real life for knowing which ends of two permanent magnets will stick together. But the north/south concept doesn't really facilitate a deep understanding of magnets. If you're curious, crack open and E+M textbook, specifically the sections about "magnetostatics." Learning about "magnetic fields" and "magnetization" are much clearer ways to understand magnets, and if you learn these concepts, the answer to this question is very clear. Without learning these concepts the question is kind of hard to answer.

Comment: @mmesser314 This the correct answer. It shouldn't be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Hold the North Pole of one magnet against the north pole of the other magnet.
This will create a system with a South Pole at each end.The magnetic field will be predominantly a quadrupole field.

Answer (score 0):

Although some theories predict their existence, there is currently no evidence for [magnetic monopoles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole).

Comment: Is it possible to maybe curve a wire or put on a core in a way to make it possible?

Comment: Monopoles do not have ends.

Answer (score 0):

Magnets that are exclusively south poles do not exist.  If they did, then they would probably be considered to have only one "end."

Electromagnets can have more than two "ends."  A [quadrupole magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_magnet) with four ends can have two south poles.

[image: Quadrupole magnets]

Comment: What's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you change the winding direction of the coil in the middle of the electromagnet. The middle point will become one pole, and both ends another.

It is the same as two ordinary magnets placed nearby with the same pole facing each other.

Answer (score -1):

This is a long comment, not an answer:

One can design an electromagnet that looks as if  it has two south poles,(simulates), though I do not see any use for this experiment.

Take the north pole and open it like a fan into such a large number of physical  lines that the field in space is below detection level.

Take the south pole and open it into a Y, the axis of the Y connected with the north line. There will be two south poles with a strong enough field for measurement.

It will require a lot of design  effort in the circuits of the electromagnet, for no real use.